# Image doesn't load on the server but does locally (heroku)

Tags: javascript, html, heroku, procfile

I have a problem. I made a site hosted on heroku. When I open up the file (index.html) locally id loads normally (same for the icon) but when I go on the site it doesn't work. The script of the site is:

```
<html>
   <style>
        some style here
    <style>
    <head>
        <title>Site</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="logo.png">
        other body
    </body>

</html>
```

The hosting one is (node.js):

```
var http = require("http");
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
fs = require('fs');


fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
});
```

The procfile is:

```
web: node main.js
```

Locally the image (and icon loads)

but on heroku it shows this

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMX3B.png)

for the icon:
[picturetwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQrsu.png)

If you need more info then comment.

Comment: There's a system on heroku that you can't upload files like image (You can google about that). I mean, at the beginning, the image will load but it won't last more than 24 hours. The solution for that is using cdn like amazon s3 bucket.